# API facebook, error al enviar parametros

Tags: api, facebook-api

Estoy tratando de enviar un post con una imagen la cual quiero que contenga el parámetro `published = false`.

En toda [esta](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo#par-metros) documentación que he leído, no hace referencia nunca a cómo se manda un parámetro.

De momento consigo publicar una imagen con este comando:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/${this.pageId}${url}&access_token=${token}
```

Pero quiero NO publicarla para obtener única y exclusivamente el ID de la imagen para, posteriormente, meterle el texto correspondiente, links, etc...

¿Cómo puedo mandar el parámetro published=false?
Pd: A través de la url que pasé antes no funciona.